# Trouble in installing jupyter using pip installer

Tags: python, pip, installation, jupyter

I'm having a trouble installing jupyter using pip. pip is already up-to-date.

[Screenshot of errors] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ2eA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is mentioned in the second from the last line in the screenshot. Pip does not have permission to write to that directory. You will need to run cmd as admin.

Here is a short article from [microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx).